# React JS Application works very slow on Localhost but runs proper on Azure server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localhost

I'm new to react and was given a product to work on fixes and updates.

There is a big list of dev-/dependencies. The application runs extremely slow when served on localhost using npm start.

However when I deploy on azure server, it works perfectly.

Slow in the sense extremely slow, like when I open a drop-down, it opens after almost 7-8 seconds. This gets even slower every time it hot-reloads and I have to run npm cache clean and serve again to gain some speed around 3-4 sec. This makes my development extremely slow.

Application is build using Material UI and has react-redux.

**Localhost**
[image: LocalHost]

**Azure**
[image: Azure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. React DevTools was enabled for localhost.

Comment: How you make it run faster because I am having the same issue Please guide

Comment: @ProgrammingHobby in my main file, the React DevTools was enabled for localhost. So I disabled it

Comment: Actually the problem with mine was that there was an error from which the browser showed the page not responding.As I removed that error the localhost worked normally.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

React Dev Tools makes the loading slow so just disable the React Dev Tools Extension and the page will load at a fast rate as normal.
[image]